# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (only on simulator) when reading fetchedObjects property of NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

This issue strangely only occurs on iOS simulator.

After I make a change and save my data, and then try and access the controller's fetchedObjects I get a bad access error.

Even if I just try and check if fetchedObjects is nil, I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS access. The controller definitely exists and I can print the description of it or for example the fetchRequest property. It's just when accessing the fetchedObjects array it errors.

I'm not sure how to debug this as it seems to come from the SDK.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some code would be helpful

Comment: The stack trace would be helpful as well

Comment: I'll provide the stack trace and code (somehow abbreviated!) shortly. I just realised this crash only happens on the simulator - which is interesting.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling app from simulator then installing it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've experienced something similar and I think it might be an issue in the latest Xcode betas. If you are using batched fetched requests and are on the Xcode 6.3 (and possibly 6.2) then I think it's just a bug. You'll have to work around it and hope it's fixed soon.

Try removing your batching and seeing if this still happens.

FYI, I filed a bug report to Apple for this, and if it's also the case for you then you should do the same. More bug reports = more attention!

Comment: You're totally right! Lifesaver. Disabling batching fixes it. Hope its resolved in the main release. Thank you so much!

Comment: IMPORTANT: fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 0 solved an unexpectedly app crash when accessing fetchedResultController.sections[].objects and fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects. My app was running on the device and disconnected from Xcode. (Xcode 7.3 iOS 9.3)

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had a similar issue in iOS 9.1.

Turns out I needed to **turn ON batching** on the `NSFetchRequest` and set it to a number larger than the fetchedObjects count to fix it:

```
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 1_000_000
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue too. ios 10 , xcode 8.3.3. In simulator and real device.

when I set myFetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 30 // not 0

then in tableViewController. access to myFetchResutlController.fetchedObejcts will get that error.